# How to remove extra double quotes rather than open and closing double quotes in a line of text using bash script

Tags: regex, bash, postgresql, shell, pattern-matching

I have a text file, I want to copy it into CSV file and after that CSV file copy to  PostgreSQL table.

My input text file is(old_sample.txt) ,

```
SVCOP,"12980","2019"0627","1DEX","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS "1"","I","0.4","0.4","15.95","10.80","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","38.03","30.17","53.98","40.97","FULL SYNTHETIC MOTOR OIL.","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS ''1''","91","LANE","LANE","L","LA MERE","125.00","125.00","","0.00","0.00","0","0","0","||||||||||||||||||||||||","N"
```

I have to use the below code

```
cat old_sample.txt
printf "\n"
echo "____________________________________"
printf "\n"
cat old_sample.txt | sed ': again
s/\("[^",]*\)"\([^",]*"\)/\1\2/g
t again
s/""/"/g'
```

Output is

```
SVCOP,"12980","2019"0627","1DEX","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS "1"","I","0.4","0.4","15.95","10.80","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","38.03","30.17","53.98","40.97","FULL SYNTHETIC MOTOR OIL.","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS ''1''","91","LANE","LANE","L","LA MERE","125.00","125.00","","0.00","0.00","0","0","0","||||||||||||||||||||||||","N"
```

```
SVCOP,"12980","20190627","1DEX","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS "1","I","0.4","0.4","15.95","10.80","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","38.03","30.17","53.98","40.97","FULL SYNTHETIC MOTOR OIL.","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS ''1''","91","LANE","LANE","L","LA MERE","125.00","125.00",","0.00","0.00","0","0","0","||||||||||||||||||||||||","N"
```

The problem  is `"LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS "1""`

"1" this double quotes not removed due to comma is present inside the double quotes but "2019"0627"  this works fine so I want to remove all double quotes inside string enclosed in open and closed double-quotes.otherwise it will show a database error.

This is my code

```
nl -ba -nln -s, < old_sample.txt | sed ': again
                                      s/\("[^",]*\)"\([^",]*"\)/\1\2/g
                                      t again' | grep 'SVCPTS' > old_sample.csv
psql_local <<SQL || die "Failed to import parts data"
        \copy sample_table from 'old_sample.csv' with (format csv, header false)
SQL
```

My target output is

```
SVCOP,"12980","20190627","1DEX","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS 1","I","0.4","0.4","15.95","10.80","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","38.03","30.17","53.98","40.97","FULL SYNTHETIC MOTOR OIL.","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS ''1''","91","LANE","LANE","L","LA MERE","125.00","125.00","","0.00","0.00","0","0","0","||||||||||||||||||||||||","N"
```

Comment: _The problem is `"LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS "1""`_ yet in the sample it is `"LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS ''1''"` (`"` vs `''`). Which one is it?

Comment: "LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS "1""                this one

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if I were doing this, I would reach for a utility program.  I think you **may** be able to achieve it by finding the right RegEx - but it might end up being quite complex.

Using something like [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/) - specifically, [the csvformat command](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvformat.html) seems a lot easier.  It would also be more reliable if you need to re-use this script with other data in the future (which could have newlines in some fields, or other situations you may need to account for).

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
while IFS= read -r str; do          # assign a variable "str" to a line
    while true; do                  # infinite loop
        str2=$(sed 's/\([^,]\)"\([^,]\)/\1\2/g' <<< "$str")
        [[ "$str2" = "$str" ]] && break
                                    # if there is no change, exit the loop
        str="$str2"                 # update "str" for next iteration
    done
    echo "$str"
done < "old_sample.txt"
```

Output:

```
SVCOP,"12980","20190627","1DEX","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS 1","I","0.4","0.4","15.95","10.80","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","38.03","30.17","53.98","40.97","FULL SYNTHETIC MOTOR OIL.","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS ''1''","91","LANE","LANE","L","LA MERE","125.00","125.00","","0.00","0.00","0","0","0","||||||||||||||||||||||||","N"
```

- The regex `\([^,]\)"\([^,]\)` matches a double quote which is surrounded
  by *non*-comma characters.
- It loops until all extra doouble quotes are removed.
- The script above will work for the provided example but may not be robust
  enough for arbitrary inputs. It is recommended to introduce a tool
  which is able to parse csv files for reliable results as chrisputnam9 suggests.

**[EDIT]**
If your file has CR+LF line endings, please try instead:

```
while IFS= read -r str; do      # assign a variable "str" to a line
    while true; do              # infinite loop
        str2=$(sed 's/\([^,]\)"\([^,]\)/\1\2/g' <<< "$str")
        [[ "$str2" = "$str" ]] && break
                                # if there is no change, exit the loop
        str="$str2"             # update "str" for next iteration
    done
#   echo "$str"                 # add LF at the end of the output line
    echo -ne "$str\r\n"         # add CR+LF at the end of the output line
done < <(tr -d "\r" < "VehSer_NEWM11_test.txt")
                                # remove CR code
```

BTW if `perl` is your option, following code will work much faster:

```
perl -pe '1 while s/([^,])"([^,\r])/$1$2/g' VehSer_NEWM11_test.txt
```

Comment: Actually my text file not contain  one single line , there are lot of texts line  but using this code  bash is hang but if it  is above single line then it working fine.

Comment: @SherinGreen thank you for the feedback. I've updated my code to process the file line by line to support multiple lines. Would you please try it? If It does not still work, I'd appreciate if you can provide a multi-line sample (not full lines but minimal lines) which breaks my code. Thank you in advance. BR.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this code with my input file but the processing hangs. I will share that  text file    shared link --->https://drive.google.com/file/d/13G6xIZXUyFhf2XR9ddst9Ho86OUo9uvR/view?usp=sharing  <---.My target is i need to     copy this file content to   csv after that  csv copy to a table in postgreSQl table.

Comment: @SherinGreen thank you for sharing your file. It helps me a lot. I've noticed your
file contains CR+LF line endings which was out of my assumption.
I've added a new version to support the CR+LF line endings. It supposingly 
works in my environment, although it takes several minutes to complete.
Would you please test it again? Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you
for your support. BR.

Comment: Hi,I have test above code but   there is no process ending,  line of string  displayed in terminal many times

Comment: Is an identical line printed out repeatedly or just printing the lines for a long time? In case of the latter, please redirect the output to another file of an arbitrary filename and wait for a while to complete.

Comment: printing the lines for a long time

Comment: The script above outputs the result to the `standard output`. If you want to save it to a file, please execute with something like: `./thisscript.sh > new_sample.txt`.

Comment: Hi, I have tested above  Perl code  and i tried to copy to csv further i copy that csv to file then i got error   due to double quotes when i check the file   i found that  SVCPTS,"18073","20191219","","5/8"HOSE","HOSE","1","0.00","10.95","0.00","10.95","GM","1","GM"                       "5/8"HOSE"  This one  have issue.Line number is  35262

Comment: Hmm... My result with Perl of line number 35262 is: `SVCPTS,"18073","20191219","","5/8 HOSE","HOSE","1","0.00","10.95","0.00","10.95","GM","1","GM"` and looks fine. Would you provide your execution environment? (OS name/version, bash version, and Perl version)

Comment: BTW what is your operation or a tool to `copy to csv`? The output file is already in csv format then you can open it just by changing its extension to `csv`. I can open it with Excel with no problem.

Comment: perl -pe '1 while s/([^,])"([^,\r])/$1$2/g' VehSer_NEWM11_test.txt      is   this update the  source file? if its true   then i have opened  it     and seems that  SVCPTS,"18073","20191219","","5/8" HOSE","HOSE","1","0.00","10.95","0.00","10.95","GM","1","GM" @ line  35262

Comment: No update with the perl code. It is the latest one. Same code and same input, but different result. Puzzling.

Comment: Would you please extract the line 35262 only from the input file, save it as a new file and run the code wirh the  input?

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it in one command so i've made this

```
 $ sed "s/['\"]//g; s/,/\",\"/g; s/\",\" /, /g; s/,,/,\"\",/g; s/$/\"/; s/\"//" file
SVCOP,"12980","20190627","1DEX","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS 1","I,0.4","0.4","15.95","10.80","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","38.03","30.17","53.98","40.97","FULL SYNTHETIC MOTOR OIL.","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS 1","91","LANE","LANE","L,LA MERE","125.00","125.00,"",0.00","0.00","0,0","0,||||||||||||||||||||||||","N"
```

Or this if you need `''1''`

```
$ sed 's/"//g; s/,/","/g; s/"," /, /g; s/,,/,"",/g; s/$/"/; s/"//' file
SVCOP,"12980","20190627","1DEX","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS 1","I","0.4","0.4","15.95","10.80","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","38.03","30.17","53.98","40.97","FULL SYNTHETIC MOTOR OIL.","LUBE, OIL & FILTER - DEXOS ''1''","91","LANE","LANE","L","LA MERE","125.00","125.00","","0.00","0.00","0","0","0","||||||||||||||||||||||||","N"
```